# How to replace just the capture group 2 in VIM with some text

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I am using below regex to abc1,cde2,efg3 replace with hello but somehow it's not working

```
 :%s/\(\d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2\}\s\)\([A-z0-9]*\)/hello/gc
```

Mar 17 02:25:01 abc1 micro: Starting use.slice.

Mar 17 02:25:01 cde2 micro: Starting use.slic

mar 17 02:25:01 efg3 micro: Starting use.slic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this substitute command in `vim`:

```
%s/\v(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/\1hello/g
```

- Here `\v` is used for **very magic** that avoids escaping as per older BRE syntax.
- `\1` is back-reference of captured group #1

Comment: You mean we can use perl's like syntax with `\v` ? (I mean \w \d \W \W etc...)

Comment: @GillesQuenot `\v` means that you don't have to escape all characters that have special meaning, see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\v . I'm sure Perl has some regex features that Vim doesn't have.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\zs` to set where the match will start in the substitution.

```
:%s/\d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2\}\s\zs[A-z0-9]*/hello/gc
```

For more help see `:h /\zs`